# ボタンが押された際にアクションを呼びたい

Tags: javascript, java, html, struts

Struts 1.3でWebアプリケーションを開発しています。
そこで`html:button`を利用した処理を行っているのですが、
以下のJavaScriptエラーが表示されます。

```
TypeError: document.XxxForm.submit is not a function
```

jspの記述は

```
<html>
…
<script language="javascript">
    function func(){
        document.XxxForm.submit();
    }
</script>
…
<html:form action="/act1">
    <html:submit property="AaaButton" value="Aaa"/>
    <html:button property="BbbButton" value="Bbb" onclick="func()"/>
</html:form>
<html:form action="/act2">
</html:form>
…
</html>
```

となっています。

Bbbボタンが押下された際にact2（act1とは別の）アクションを呼びたいと考えております。
エラーの解決方法、または実現方法等、分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、
回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: タグから分かる情報をタイトルに書かないでください。バージョン情報は質問文の中に書いて頂ければと思います。詳しくは[こちらのメタ投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2420/19110)をご覧ください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 最終的にブラウザが読み込む HTML/JavaScript コードを提示できますか? 問題は Safari と Chrome のみで発生しますか?

Answer (score 0):

まず、document.XxxForm.submit is not a function　というエラーですが、原因はdocument.XxxForm　というFormが存在しないからです。

func()関数で、act2アクションを呼びたいという事ですから、func()関数で下記のFormのSubmitを呼び出せば良いのだと思います。

```
<html:form action="/act2">
</html:form>
```

だとすると、上記の部分を以下のように変更してください。

```
<html:form name="XxxForm" action="/act2">
</html:form>
```

FormにXxxFormという名前を設定することで、document.XxxForm.submit()でact2が呼び出せるようになるはずです。

Comment: Fumu 7 さん　回答ありがとうございます。 >FormにXxxFormという名前を設定することで、document.XxxForm.submit()でact2が呼び出せるようになるはずです。 html:form で name を指定すると "TLDによると、タグ form の属性 name は無効です" とエラーになってしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

document.forms[0].submit()を使ってみてください。